# A thousand JPEG images in a Word document: how can I format them in the same way?

Tags: vba, formatting, microsoft-word, jpeg

Please suppose you have a Microsoft Word 2007 document: you have just inserted in it about a thousand of JPEG images.

With the first image, you do right-click, then FORMAT PICTURE, then option "RECOLOR", and then select "BLACK AND WHITE" in the second row "COLOR MODES".

How can you automate the process of giving the same "format picture" command to the other 999 JPEG images?

I have just tried with FORMAT PAINTER, but I did not have success.

Any clues?

This is a similar QUESTION with NO ANSWERS: http://thedailyreviewer.com/windowsapps/view/formatting-all-pictures-in-a-word-document-in-one-go-11962810

*How do I select all pictures in one go, for consistent formatting, so that 
they all appear the same throughout my word document, ie, so that they all 
have the same text wrapping margins, for example... and are all the same % 
size of the original?
If word doesn't allow me to 'select all' for pictures, can I copy the 
formatting of the pics and then paste it over the other pics somehow, similar 
to the format brush used for text?*

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can:

```
Dim Pic As InlineShape
For Each Pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  Pic.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureGrayscale
Next
```

Comment: OK, but I wish to pass to "Black and White", and not Grayscale. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `msoPictureBlackAndWhite` instead of `msoPictureGrayscale` but it will probably look terrible - the recolour option seems to use grayscale

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind suggestion. My original problem was the following: I have a PDF obtained transforming a PPT into PDF, with a horrible cyan background, and black characters. I have transformed the PDF into 100 JPEG files, I have included them into a Word 2007 document, and at last I have switched them to Black_and_White, removing the background and leaving only the black characters. Many thanks for your kind contribution ;-)

Comment: After migration of my question from stackoverflow to superuser, it was necessary to accept AGAIN your answer, Alex K: it sounds like very strange!  Thank you AGAIN ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, many thanks to Alex K., the solution is the following:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
Dim Pic As InlineShape
For Each Pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  Pic.PictureFormat.ColorType = msoPictureBlackAndWhite
Next
End Sub
```

I have accepted Alex K. solution, because he found the right way to solve the problem.  The right keyword is msoPictureBlackAndWhite instead of msoPictureGrayscale.

Many thanks, Alex K. ;-)

Comment: Given the details you added in your second comment, `msoPictureBlackAndWhite` is, indeed, correct (you really do want stark Black and White). For *most* pictures, `msoPictureGrayscale` is preferrable, and that wasn't clear in the original question. +1 for credit where due.